# I have done text classification using LSTM architecture, the problem with this architecture is it overfits

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, text-classification

LSTM architecture to classify text within 30 categories, problem is it over fitting after 3 epochs,any suggestions to avoid over fitting ?

```
model.add(Embedding(max_words, embedding_dimension, input_length=X.shape[1]))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(30, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
print(model.summary())
```

Comment: Try adding more `Dense` layers along with `Dropout` layers.

Comment: Overfitting depends on many factor such as the number of samples, the class distribution (are they equally represented), the model's architecture, etc. Could you give us more information about the dataset?

Comment: @AntoineDubuis the data set contains job descriptions and their categories (like computer it, business operations etc), data set is balanced and there are 30 categories.

Comment: Your final activation function should probably be 'softmax' if you are using 'categorical_crossentropy'.  Sigmoid would be more appropriate if it is a multi-class problem.  Fix this first before trying dropout or more layers.  More layers will add more ability to overfit.  Dropout will mostly cause covariance in lower layers and isn't actually as a great regularizer as people thought back in 2015.  Instead of a [dense(30), dropout(0.5)] you can achieve a very similar regularization effect by using just dense(15) but the bonus is that it computers faster and doesn't force covariance.

Comment: There can be many reasons for over fitting, it would be difficult to say from that code. But I would suggest you to consider weights parameter in Embedding layer by using some pre trained word to vec model like `GoogleNewsVector`. And try adding some dropout techniques like `SpacialDroupout`, and in LSTM layer also you can  use dropout and recurrent dropout.